# Process builder: case owner never equal to current user?

Tags: process-builder, case, case-comment

My process starts with this condition on a CaseComment:

[image]

What it should do: start an action *only* when the logged in user is *not* equal to the owner of the Case to which the CaseComment belongs.

But what I see is that this condition is always met, never the FALSE path is taken in the process. What am I doing wrong here?

Normally, I would create a formula on the CaseComment object that compares these two values, but it is not possible to create custom fields on CaseComments.

Changing the condition to a formula:

```
[CaseComment].Parent.OwnerId != $User.Id
```

does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of googling I got some inspiration and tried this as formula:

```
LEFT([CaseComment].Parent.OwnerId, 15) != LEFT($User.Id, 15)
```

And that works!

Comment: Not sure, haven't tried it, but `{!CASESAFEID($User.Id)}` would also work, right? instead of using substring.